# Alternative way of asking "how long does a certain event/activity take?"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I want to ask how long an event/activity lasts, can I ask "what is the time period of this event/activity?"

Is there any other ways of phrasing this?

Also I'm confused between `the time period` and `the period of time`. If I want to refer to something happened in the middle of an event/activity, should I say "during the period of time of this event" or "during the time period of this event" or just simply "during this event"?

Thank you

Comment: Definitely "during this event" is preferable to the other 2 choices you mention.

Answer (score 1):

"How long does this last?" will be very helpful. You can also replace "this" with the type of event.

> How long does the concert last?
>
> How long does the tour last?

"How long does this take?" is another option.

Comment: what about the differences between `the time period` and `the period of time`?

Comment: @Joji Lorel C. gave you a good answer for that in her comment to your post.

Comment: I mean, is there a difference between `the time period` and `the period of time`?

Comment: As far as the basic meaning of the phrases, no.